# Is there any cure for keloids?

Tags: topical-cream-gel, scar-tissue-scars, keloids

A keloidal scar is a fibrous tissue that occurs when skin is injured and forms over the wound to repair and protect the injury. Till now, there is no complete cure except for plastic surgery. But dermatologists say that a plastic surgery of keloids could only exacerbate the scar than diminishing completely.

Apart from surgery, is there any medication like herbal treatment that could reduce the scar? In general, is there any traditional medicine to treat keloids?

I have realised there are so-called "peptide gels". Do they work on keloids too?

Comment: Intradermal corticosteroids injection can be used to whiten the keloid.

Comment: Hey @Ak2817! We generally are not too pleased with links to products because they are easily perceived as spam. I've allowed myself to edit the question to remove the link and name of producer to the product, those did not enhance your question anyway. Furthermore, we are reluctant with giving personal experience: Everyone's way too different to make assumptions based on what some guy on the internet says, and how are we to verify that this is not some worker of said company that replies how great their product is? (Happened before). This is why I have edited your question.

Comment: Thank you @Narusan-in-coma.My aim is to know whether such gels are effective on keloids. I am happy to know any other treatments too which are good at healing keloids.